# rvest/httr performance when scraping many dynamic pages

Tags: r, performance, rvest, httr

I've seen a number of questions related to using `rvest` and `httr` to scrape data from dynamic web pages in R; however, the issue I face is related to speed/performance when scraping hundreds of pages. In particular, I am getting `character(0)` results when scraping price and text data for certain URLs in a list of ~1.5K URLs; however, if I then re-run those same URLs that returned `character(0)` (without changing my code), I get the expected outputs.

A sample of my function for scraping prices:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

    priceScraper <- function(url){
      res <- GET(url)
      doc <- read_html(content(res, as = "text")) 
      price <- doc %>% html_nodes("#price") %>% html_text()

      return(price)
    }

webPrices <- lapply(URLs_List, priceScraper)
```

My first pass at the above will take ~50 minutes for the 1.5K URLs and has a ~75% success rate. If I then take the 25% of unsuccessful rows (those that return `character(0)`) and re-run them with the exact same code, I get the expected result. So my questions are:

1) Is there a way to ensure that all data is successfully gathered on the first attempt? Perhaps I need to use `RSelenium` to allow the target page to fully load?

2) Is there a way to increase performance, especially if a delay is input into the function to ensure the web page has fully loaded? Is there a way to check that the web page has fully loaded?

Many thanks to all of you R developer gurus out there who have any insights on this topic!

Comment: just guessing, maybe, this is related to sites robots policy? Crawl-delay? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: @minem hmm it could be, but I'm not sure that would explain why I'm able to re-run those same URLs and get the expected results. My gut tells me this is a performance issue related to scaling... on a URL-by-URL basis I encounter no issues, it's only when I try to `lapply()` across 1.5K URLs that the issue begins occurring.

Comment: it is hard to guess without you specifying the urls. Also, I would split your code so all of the `GET(URL)` results are stored in a list, and then inspect what the server returned in cases when the result is `character(0)`. `urls <- lapply(URLs_List, GET)`

Comment: Can you please try using this and see if you have any change in the results?
`library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


    priceScraper <- function(url){
      res <- html_session(url)
      price <- res %>% html_nodes("#price") %>% html_text()
      return(price)
    }

webPrices <- lapply(URLs_List, priceScraper)`

Comment: @minem Storing the `GET()` results was the way to go. I had done something similar to this in an earlier iteration, but had a mistake that caused it to be useless. Your suggestion to return to this concept proved to be the most effective; it also allows me to store the URL responses, and then run experiment with multiple `html_nodes()` calls.  Many thanks for your fresh set of eyes!

Comment: @DRC so what was the problem? maybe you could answer your own question

Comment: @minem nt sure I discovered the heart of the problem, but by using your recommendation to store the `GET()` results from the URL list first (in a separate list that I called `content`) and then running the scraping functions against that list, I am now receiving the success rate I would expect. Additional benefits include that I can identify if there are bad URLs anytime one of the scraping functions fails (as I still have the `GET()` results that I can analyze), and performance time remains unchanged (not any slower to first `GET()` the URL's content and then scrape).